# gettext: No translation file found for domain: 'messages' in python

Tags: python, gettext, language-translation

So I've been trying to work with gettext in a standalone python application, not a web environment. And I've been failing to get my translations to work, now I have the following:

```
# Set the desired language from the json_data, default if not present is english
target_language = self.pdf_content_json.get("language", "en_US")

# Set the locale for the program
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, target_language)

# Set up the translation
translation = gettext.translation('messages', localedir='translations/', languages=['nl_NL'])
translation.install()
```

This is how my folder structure looks:

[image]

This is the exception I get:

````
Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: _run_module_as_main)
[Errno 2] No translation file found for domain: 'messsages'
  File "C:\Users\joren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\gettext.py", line 528, in translation
    raise FileNotFoundError(ENOENT,
  File "D:\Documents\coding\pdf_creator\app\pdf_creator\src\pdf_types\base_pdf.py", line 34, in initialise
    translation = gettext.translation('messsages', localedir='translations', languages=['nl_NL'])
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Documents\coding\pdf_creator\app\pdf_creator\main.py", line 31, in generate_checkinout_pdf
    pdf.initialise(json_data)
  File "D:\Documents\coding\pdf_creator\app\pdf_creator\main.py", line 71, in main
    generate_checkinout_pdf("checkin_report.pdf")
  File "D:\Documents\coding\pdf_creator\app\pdf_creator\main.py", line 77, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\joren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\runpy.py", line 88, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\joren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\runpy.py", line 198, in _run_module_as_main (Current frame)
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No translation file found for domain: 'messsages'```
````